# Vuejs and Kendo integration

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a problem with vuejs and kendo ui.
I need to click a tr columns

`<kendo-grid-column @click="clicked"></kendo-grid-column>`

i also used a @click.native but nothing

i've created also a template with `<a>` tag that calls "clicked" method

demo
http://dojo.telerik.com/@aldoZumaran/UTOGo

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this is not exactly what you want, but it's possible to enable Sorting on the Grid and intercept the [Sort Event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-sort) for further handling.

Change your `kendo-grid`, add:

```
:sortable='true'
@sort='callback'
```

The Callback method syntax was also a bit weird, use:

```
callback: function(e) {
    console.log(e.sort.field);
    console.log(e.sort.dir);
}
```

Maybe this is the right place to execute your actions.

***UPDATE***

It's possible to call `e.preventDefault();` in callback method to prevent default sorting action:

```
callback: function(e) {
    if (e.sort.field === 'UnitPrice') {
        console.log('Sort by Price not allowed!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```